# How to select ranged ancestor/descendent using xpath?

Tags: html, selenium, xpath

If I want to select all immediate `<p>...</p>` tag descendents of a div, I would write

```
div/p
```

If I want to select all secondary `<p>...</p>` tag descendents of a div, I would write

```
div/*/p
```

Is it possible to specify a range, instead?

```
div/descendent[1-2]::p // find all immediate and secondary descendent tags
```

Comment: This xpath selects `p` with 1 or 2 `div` ancestors but it's not numerical `//p[./parent::div[not(parent::div)] or ./parent::div[parent::div[not(parent::div)]]]`

Comment: You've tagged it Selenium, which is your only clue that you might be looking for an XPath 1.0 solution. However, if you can consider XPath 2.0+, then you have the option of `div/(*|.)/(*|.)/p`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to express this would be to use a union operator.

`div/p | div/*/p` or `(div | div/*)/p`

There isn't, to my knowledge, a particularly clean way to express the idea of selecting a descendant that has a range of ancestors, but depending on the input, something like it could be possible.

Given

```
<root>
   <div>
      <p>good</p>
   </div>
   <div>
      <foo>
         <p>also good</p>
      </foo>
   </div>
   <div>
      <foo>
         <bar>
            <p>this one is not good</p>
         </bar>
      </foo>
   </div>
</root>
```

...you could select only the wanted nodes with `//p[count(./ancestor::*) < 4]`.

This does not seem like a better solution than using the union operator in this case.

The nearest I can think of for a true range of nodes "between" the target and the parent would be something like this:

`//p[count(ancestor::*) - count(ancestor::div[1]/*) < 3]`

Comment: Thanks for the response. But keep in mind that the range `[1-2]` is the degenerate case. Larger ranges are the ones I'm really interested in.

Comment: I think there is a solution that can express the idea of "select nodes that have a certain number of ancestors that are also descendants of a specific ancestor" which I can test. I'm assuming that merely writing `div//p` is insufficient for your intended use case?

Comment: You have guessed right. I am essentially just trying to use this as a method of making my xpaths more robust to simple hierarchy changes. So instead of checking for direct element descendents, I would instead give it a range (some wiggle room). The same can be said for siblings/ancestors/etc.